# Getting error has been blocked by CORS policy when making api call

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I am getting the following error when I am trying to make an api call to [kickstarter Staff pick json endpoint](https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recommended?format=json)

This is what the error exactly looks like

> localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recommended?format=json' from
>   origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have previously encountered this error but that was when I was trying to make a local API call.

I known I can enable cors on my browser which might possibly fix the error but I am trying to avoid it.

Any ideas or fixes?

I am using axios for making api calls

```
axios.get("https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recommended?format=json").then(response => {
```

**[Update:]** Can someone also help me in figuring out how we can use it with Promise.

```
 let Base_url = axios.get(base_url)
  let StaffPick = axios.get(staffPick)


   return Promise.all(Base_url, StaffPick).then(response => {
```

Where **staff pick** is https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recommended?format=json
and 
**base_url** is: http://coincap.io/map

Comment: If an API is not CORS enabled ( or serves JSONP)  you need to use a proxy either on server you control or a third party service

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you please explain it briefly? Can you suggest a way via which i can get Kickstarter data?

Comment: Do a web search for *"ajax proxy"*

Comment: Seems fine when simply hitting that end-point from a browser... Share your get request code here...

Comment: @SakoBu you clearly didn't try it using `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` which is where CORS kicks in

Comment: Yes.. I just noticed that...

Comment: @SakoBu get result is showing the error mentioned in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this and it should work:

```
fetch(
  'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.kickstarter.com/discover/recommended?format=json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Or the equivalent with axios...

Here is live demo on code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ox7wz9ny15

Instead of writing our own proxy server we're using this one: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

Note: if you want to use this in production I would recommend writing your own proxy server... More info on CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: An explanation of why it should work would be helpful

Comment: Also, if you include how we might be able to use it promise.all? 
Take this as my second URL: http://coincap.io/map (updating the code for the same)

Comment: @KuchBhi You had a CORS issue with solved it... This is a seperate question about how to use promise.all in axios... Here are the docs: https://github.com/axios/axios